# Wordpress Multi-site get-template-directory after upgrade different

Tags: php, css, wordpress, url, multisite

One of the sites from our client got some nasty mail-scripts, we've cleaned those scripts and upgraded Wordpress from 3.1 to 4.2.

Now we have the following issue with our template, the files are not loading. The reason is a Wrong get_template_directory_uri(); URL.

It is a Wordpress Multi-Site, the file url now is: 
http://example.com/beauty/wp-content/themes/beauty/assets/css/style.css

But it is supposed to be: http://example.com/wp-content/themes/beauty/assets/css/style.css

Are there any ways to fix this issue? My php-knowledge is minimal, some ideas are appreciated!

Kind regards.

Comment: Have you tried deactivating and reactivating your current theme?